# Angular $http and Fusion Tables in IE9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-9, google-fusion-tables

I am trying a simple get request to a google fusion table in my angular controller.

```
$http.get(url)
    .success(function(data) {
        //Do stuff with data
    })
```

This works in firefox, chrome, safari and IE10+ however in IE9 (Which I am requried to support) the request fails to even send and the console shows `access is denied`. I have looked at other stackoverflow answers and I believe it is related to a Cross Origin Request. I tried [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25335435/2073800) to no avail.

I have managed to get around the issue for now using the jQuery below. However I would rather be utilising the angular library where possible. I would also like to know why the below works and my angular `$http` request does not.

```
$.ajax({
  url: urlForId.join(''),
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    //Do stuff with data
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Angular $http.jsonp() request rather than $http.get().

JSONP or “JSON with padding” is the communication technique which allows for data to be requested from a server under a different domain (also known as a Cross Origin Request). Which is what you have used in your jQuery AJAX request.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

Comment: Thanks, I had actually tried the $http.jsonp() request but in my rush I had forgotten to set the callback handler correctly. Your answer confirmed that it is what I should have been using, and made me look closer.